Confidence interval with an infinity upper limit
So, I want to try finding a variance confidence interval of a unknown distribution with a known mean (With n very large). So, I first used Central Limit Theorem so that an distribution X with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ have
$\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}} \xrightarrow{D} N(0,1)$
Now, we can find the 1-$\alpha$ confidence interval, in which the random interval being:
$ \begin{align*}
Pr\left(-z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}<\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}}<z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right) &= 1-\alpha \\
Pr\left(0<\left|\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}}\right|<z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right) &= 1-\alpha \\
Pr\left(0<\left(\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}}\right)^2<z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2\right) &= 1-\alpha \\
Pr\left(0<\frac{(\bar{X}-\mu)^2}{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}<z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2\right) &= 1-\alpha \\
Pr\left(\frac{1}{z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2}<\frac{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}{(\bar{X}-\mu)^2}<\infty\right) &= 1-\alpha \\
Pr\left(\frac{n(\bar{X}-\mu)^2}{z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2}<\sigma^2<\infty\right) &= 1-\alpha
\end{align*}$
So, with $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$, we have a (1-$\alpha$) confidence interval being $\left(\frac{n(\bar{x}-\mu)^2}{z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2}, \infty\right)$
Is there something wrong with this? If not, can we have an infinity upper limit for a confidence interval?

There's nothing wrong with $\infty$ as a confidence limit, any one-sided interval will result in that. For that reason most then still report the two-sided $2\alpha$ interval. That is not the result of $1/0$ (your 5th step) however.

I think you went astray at the very first step by artificially imposing $0$ as a lower limit. You have, in effect, computed just a lower confidence limit for $\sigma.$ For a two-sided limit you would use a nonzero lower bound.  Regardless, this is not a stable or reliable approach because the CLT won't be very helpful until you have an enormous sample size.

Take a look at this site https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/how-to-prove-that-1-2/, which will demonstrate to you that 2=1. What, you do not believe this? Well, you have done the same thing i(divide by 0) n step 5 of your derivation; so you final result is about as valid as the final result from the link.

@whuber I used the absolute value theorem where if $-a<b<a$, then $|b|<a$, where $0 \leq |b|$ for a real number a and b where a > 0. Is that not allowed? Although it is true that this will only work for n very large, I'll add that in the question

Well, what would contradict the fact that for a positive value a and b where $0 \leq a < b$, then $\frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{a}$ with $\frac{1}{a}$ not having an upper limit, which means infinity? I'm not saying specifically that 1/0 means infinity

What exactly does this "absolute value theorem" state?

@whuber Oh wait, "absolute value theorem" is a completely thing, I apologize. It's more of an absolute value property, really, referring to the Introduction to Real Analysis book, Theorem 2.2.2 (c) about if $c \geq 0$, then $|a| \leq c$ if and only if $-c \leq a \leq c$, so I figure I can apply that to this case as well. Is that assumption wrong?

It's not wrong--it's just not very relevant to this confidence interval question and is potentially misleading.

Relying on the central limit theorem, there is nothing wrong with the derivation of this confidence interval for $\sigma^2$.  Here is a quick sanity check verifying that the coverage is indeed very close to $1-\alpha$ when the data is uniform rather than normally distributed:
alpha <- .05
mu <- 1/2
sigma2 <- 1/12
n <- 10
mean(replicate(1e+6, {
  x <- runif(n)
  lower <- n*(mean(x)-mu)^2/qnorm(alpha/2, lower.tail = FALSE)^2
  lower < sigma2 & sigma2 < Inf
}))
#> [1] 0.951169

Created on 2024-11-29 with reprex v2.1.0
That said, shorter approximate intervals can be constructed using ideas similar to the studentized bootstrap.  Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ denote the observed data and let $\hat\sigma=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2$ denote the sample variance.  Assuming that
$$
\frac{\hat\sigma^2}{\sigma^2} \tag{1}
$$
has a distribution which is approximately independent of the model parameters, non-parametric bootstrap replicates, $$
\frac{\hat\sigma_b^2}{\hat\sigma^2}, \tag{2}
$$
of this (approximate) pivotal quantity,
can be obtained by resampling $x_1^b,x_2^b,\dots,x_n^b$ from the original data $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ and computing $\hat\sigma_b^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}(x_i^b-\bar x^b)^2$ for each bootstrap sample.  Letting $\hat q_{\alpha/2}$ and $\hat q_{1-\alpha/2}$ denote the empirical quantiles of (2), it follows that
$$
P(\hat q_{\alpha/2} < \frac{\hat\sigma^2}{\sigma^2} < \hat q_{1-\alpha/2}) \approx 1-\alpha
$$
Thus
$$
P(\frac{\hat\sigma^2}{\hat q_{1-\alpha/2}} < \sigma^2 < \frac{\hat\sigma^2}{\hat q_{\alpha/2}}) \approx 1-\alpha
$$
and so $(\frac{\hat\sigma^2}{\hat q_{1-\alpha/2}},\frac{\hat\sigma^2}{\hat q_{\alpha/2}})$ is an approximate $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval for $\sigma^2$.
